Increase Width of Multiselect dropdown used as Input parameter in SSRS Report?
Is there any way to increase width of multiselect dropdown used as Input parameter in SSRS report? I am using Visual Studio 2022.
No property is available currently in SSRS to change the width. For normal dropdown width is adjusted based on data.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
